# Should autogen.sh be included in a tarball?

Tags: release, autotools

I have seen many tarballs do not include an `autogen.sh` file, but I have seen it in some other tarballs.

What is the rationale for including or not including `autogen.sh` in a tarball?

Answer (score 6):

If you're releasing a source distribution from some kind of release branch, then IMHO there is no need to include this.

*autogen.sh* should only be included in development releases.

Since you use it to generate *./configure* and stuff, there is no need to do this in release packages.

Of course if you're targeting developers mainly, your audience may find *autogen.sh* files useful.

Comment: `configure`, not `configure.sh`.

Answer (score 4):

If your autogen/bootstap does more than what `autoreconf` does, then please, please, include it. It makes life *much* easier for people modifiying the released tarball (it might be necessary to re-autogen after a patch is applied).

Comment: what else might it be doing other than 'autoreconf -i'?

Comment: gtkdocize, intltoolize, git submodule update, auto-configure etc etc